# input from file in java

Tags: java, file-io

I am java beginner learner and i am trying to output the data on file which i call a.txt. need help i have no idea y i am getting exception error file not open . i put a.txt in the same directory in  which i have main and readfile.

```
- main path : C:\Users\Navdeep\Desktop\java\assign1\src\assign1

- readfile : C:\Users\Navdeep\Desktop\java\assign1\src\assign1

- a.txt :  C:\Users\Navdeep\Desktop\java\assign1\src\assign1
```

Thanks in advance .

main.java

```
package assign1;

public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        readfile r = new readfile();
        r.openFile();
        r.readFile();
        r.closeFile();
    }
}
```

---

readile.java

```
package assign1;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class readfile {
    private Scanner x;

    public void openFile() {
        try {
            x = new Scanner(new File("a.txt"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("file not open \n");
        }
    }

    public void readFile() {
        while (x.hasNext()) {
            String Agent = x.next();
            String request_type = x.next();
            String classtype = x.next();
            String numberofseat = x.next();
            String arrivaltime = x.next();

            System.out.printf("%s %s %s %s %s \n", Agent, 
                    request_type, classtype, numberofseat, arrivaltime);
        }
    }
    public void closeFile() {
        x.close();
    }
}
```

---

a.txt

```
1 r e 1 0
2 r e 1 1
```

Comment: How do you compile and what directory do you start your program from?

Comment: m using eclipse  and m getting output file not open always.

Comment: a.txt has to be on the ["classpath"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html) of the jvm when you start your program.

Comment: i am new to java kind of beginner , i created a project. give a name assign1 then i slected src added main and readfile. write code in both of them and make a txt file (a.txt) and place it in the src of assign1.

Comment: The `src` directory won't be there at runtime in most cases. You need to put it somewhere else.

Answer (score 2):

If you use a `File` with a relative path, it is assumed relative to the "current user directory". What's the "current user directory"? See the doc:

> A relative pathname, in contrast, must be interpreted in terms of information taken from some other pathname. By default the classes in the java.io package always resolve relative pathnames against the current user directory. This directory is named by the system property user.dir, and is typically the directory in which the Java virtual machine was invoked.

Also from the doc:

> On UNIX systems, a relative pathname is made absolute by resolving it against the current user directory. On Microsoft Windows systems, a relative pathname is made absolute by resolving it against the current directory of the drive named by the pathname, if any; if not, it is resolved against the current user directory.

So one way to get the `File` to be found using a relative path would be to start the JVM in the directory with the file.

However, this approach can be kind of limiting since it constrains you to always start the JVM in a certain directory.

As an alternative, you might consider using `ClassLoader#getResourceAsStream`. This allows you to load any resource that is on the JVM's "classpath". The classpath can be configured in a number of different ways, including at launch time using arguments to the JVM. So I would suggest using that, rather than initializing your `Scanner` with a `File`. This would look like:

```
InputStream is = StackOverflow.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("a.txt");
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(is);
```

Now, when using `getResourceAsStream`, you have to make sure that the file referenced is on the [classpath](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html) of the Java Virtual Machine process which holds your program.

You've said in comments that you're using Eclipse.

In Eclipse, you can set the classpath for an execution by doing the following:

1) After running the program at least once, click on the little dropdown arrow next to the bug or the play sign.

2) Click on "Debug configurations" or "Run Configurations".

3) In the left sidebar, select the run configuration named after the program you're running

4) Click on the "Classpath" tab

5) Click on "User Entries"

6) Click on "Advanced"

7) Select "Add Folders"

8) Select the folder where a.txt resides.

Once you have done this, you can run the program using the run configuration you have just set up, and a.txt will be found.

### Basic idea of classpath

The classpath represents the resources that the JVM (Java Virtual Machine) holding your program knows about while it's running. If you are familiar with working from a command line, you can think of it as analogous to your OS's "PATH" environment variable.

You can read about it in depth [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html).

Comment: Thanks alot mate. problem solved instead of putting the txt file in src i put that in assign1 directory it start working now .

Comment: now my milestone is to get the input of file as an command line ie instead of passing it in the code i have to take the file as command line argument and so some work on it. any help for command line input really appreciated.

Comment: There are a few ways of going about this. Since you're already using Scanner, I'd recommend using that. See details [here](http://www.codejava.net/java-se/file-io/3-ways-for-reading-input-from-the-user-in-the-console).

Comment: This is wrong.  `new File` has nothing to do with the classpath.

Comment: `new File` doesn't have anything to do with the classpath, but passing a classpath into a `Scanner` does. Do you think `Scanner` looks through the whole filesystem for Files specified with relative paths?

Comment: I suppose it could be looking relative to the directory the JVM was launched in, and that directory only. There seem to be some things out there which follow that convention. Of course, `getResourceAsStream` looks relative to the classpath, and I'd been assuming it used that to get an `InputStream` on the file. Unfortunately the [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner(java.io.File)) documentation is strangely silent on this matter.

Comment: @Nav: Given the seeming ambiguity of `Scanner`'s doc, I have edited my answer to recommend using `getResourceAsStream` directly rather than guessing that it's using that method with the path from the `File` object under the hood.

Comment: Scanner's documentation is not ambiguous.  A relative `File` is always relative to the current directory of the Java process, just like in all other languages.  There is no mystery to it.

Comment: @augray  Thanks alot mate appreciated.

Comment: @augray  mate anyhelp for getting file.txt as command line arguments .

Comment: say same above example in the code instead to giving name of the file in code i want to pass the file  as command line ie  (java main a.txt) if i run it in terminal

Comment: @VGR Thank you for pointing out that there's a convention for treating relative paths for `Files` (though it looks like it's apparently not always precisely the running directory). I have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Nav: if you have another question, I suggest reading [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html). If that doesn't help, search to see if your question has been answered. If you're still having trouble after that, post another question.

Comment: A relative `File` is always relative to the current working directory.  Note that the `user.dir` system property must be set when Java starts; setting it at runtime has no effect.

Comment: Not *always*. Apparently on Windows it can also be the current directory of a drive other than the one you launched the JVM from if the relative path names a directory. From the File doc: "On UNIX systems, a relative pathname is made absolute by resolving it against the current user directory. On Microsoft Windows systems, a relative pathname is made absolute by resolving it against the current directory of the drive named by the pathname, if any; if not, it is resolved against the current user directory." I have edited my answer to reflect that setting this property at runtime has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting the file in src folder put the txt file in the project ie outside the src.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one using BufferedReader.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // check for arguments. this expects only one argument @index [0]
        if (args.length < 1) {
            System.out.println("Please Specify your file");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        // Found atleast one argument
        FileReader reader = null;
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
        // Prefer using a buffered reader depending on size of your file
        try {
            reader = new FileReader(new File(args[0]));
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(reader);
            StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
               content.append(line);
            System.out.println(content.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
        // dont forget to close your streams
            try {
                if (bufferedReader != null)
                   bufferedReader.close();
                if (reader != null)
                    reader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
         }
       }
    }
```

Let me know if you have any isues.

## Good_luck_programming!

Comment: @ Olu Doug  i need help in getting file input from command line instead of hard coded i don't want to write the input file in the code the requirement is the pass the file as a command line argument . if any help regarding that really appreciated

Comment: is this file being stored in a specific location or from anywhere?

Comment: file saving  in the directory was the older problem which was solved by changing directory.

Comment: i have a assignment to do in that requirement is to input file from command line do some work on it then output the result . i couldnt find anthing useful on internet how to do that.

Comment: that main method handles commandline args.. **java Program /path/to/file/a.txt**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88529/discussion-between-olu-doug-and-nav).